# Best way to implement a "parameter view" like in Visual Studio - TemplateSelector or what?

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplateselector

I am building a tool and want to have a listview with parameters.

i have a base class called Parameter and many different derived classes, for example:
ParameterAddress, ParameterBool, ParameterString, ParameterScreen, ...

Each Parameter looks a bit different..

ParameterBool: Label + Checkbox

ParameterString: Label + Textbox

ParamterAddress: Label + Textbox + Button (for a new Dialog)

...

I have done this in my first try with an DataTemplateSelector.

Was nice, works "well"..

In my window i implemented the events like text changed, button clicked and so on..

but now i want to use this parameter view in another window too and dont want to copy the same text changed, button clicked events in each window again..

So my second try was to build in this into my parameter class.

Each Parameter class will have an Stackpanel and each derived class adds its Controls into it and can so handle whatever events just in one place!

But now in my listview only comes up the text "....Stackpanel" .

I think way 1 was a better direction, way 2 could work anyway ..

But what would be the "best" way?

**EDIT**

here are my actual datatemplates:

```
    <Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="textBoxTemplate">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value}" Width="100"></TextBox>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="checkBoxTemplate">
        <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value}" IsThreeState="False"></CheckBox>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="screen_template">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value}" Width="100"></TextBox>
            <Button Content="..." Click="btn_screenlist_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="address_template">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Value}" Width="100"></TextBox>
            <Button Content="..." Click="btn_address_Click" />
        </StackPanel>
    </DataTemplate>

    <local:ParameterTemplateSelector
        x:Key="parameterTemplateSelector"
        TextBoxTemplate="{StaticResource textBoxTemplate}"
        CheckBoxTemplate="{StaticResource checkBoxTemplate}"
        Screen_template="{StaticResource screen_template}"
        Address_template="{StaticResource address_template}"
        />

</Window.Resources>
```

in my opinion its very unusable..

you have to maintain so many peaces of code to work..

1. create a new template
2. put it into the datatemplate resource
3. dont forget to put it into the datatemplateselector class

with having my "controls" directly in my class i have only this one peace of code.. ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some hours playing around, researching, reading and testing ..

Here is my actual solution, which works fine in multiple windows !

Please leave some comments, improvements, whatever .. Thanks.

I am having now a Parameter.cs and Parameter.xaml

**Parameter.xaml**

```
<ResourceDictionary
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:locale="clr-namespace:tests"
>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type locale:ParameterString}">
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Value}" MinWidth="100"></TextBox>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type locale:ParameterBool}">
    <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Value}"/>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type locale:ParameterAddress}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Label Content="{Binding Name}"/>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Value, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" MinWidth="100"/>
        <Button
            Content="..."
            Width="{Binding ActualHeight, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
            Command="{Binding EditAddrCmd}"
            />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Snippet of **Parameter.cs**

```
public class ParameterAddress : Parameter
{
    ControllerList controllers;

    #region constructors

    public ParameterAddress (ControllerList controllers, String address)
    {
        this.controllers=controllers;

        Name="Address";
        Value=address;

        EditAddrCmd=new RelayCommand(ex => EditAddrCmdExec(), cex => EditAddrCmdCanExec());
    }

    // ..

    #endregion // constructors

    #region commands

    public ICommand EditAddrCmd { get; internal set; }
    private void EditAddrCmdExec ()
    {
        // open dialog to edit address and save to <Value>
    }
    private bool EditAddrCmdCanExec ()
    {
        return true;
    }

    #endregion // comannds

    public override bool isValid ()
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

now i simply add to each window where i want to use these parameters the Parameter.xaml to its Resources:

**SomeWindow.xaml**

```
<Window.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="Parameter.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Window.Resources>
```

@SnowballTwo
did you mean this way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

You should make Datatemplates without keys pointing to your derives parameter class types. Wpf will automatically show the most suitable template for each class.

As for the textchanged or click-events, you should hang your "ontextchanged" or "isCheckedChanged) into the setter of the binding target (e.g. parameter.Text or parameter.IsTrue).
The OnClick of Buttons should be replaced with a proper command.

Whatever you did: don't instanciate controls in code behind ... thats the worst way to do it.

Comment: thank you for your feedback! yesterday a took a look into commands and MVVM behaviors.. need to learn a bit more about it, but sounds pretty nice.. could you explain it a bit more what do you mean with "Datatemplates without keys pointing to your derives parameter class types"? i will edit my question to show you my actual templates .. and next question is, where to place these templates??? dont want to put them into each window??!!